# Ubuntu 22.04 How to lock users from changing wifi settings

Tags: linux, administrator, wifi-configuration, web-filtering, ubuntu-22.04

I'm currently using OpenDNS to filter adult content on Ubuntu and I want to be able to prevent users from changing the DNS settings without the use of a password.

[Specifically this tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBQv1.png)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is on the router.  You

1. Either block port 53 passthrough
2. Or redirect all port 53 traffic to OpenDNS

[Understanding DNS Port 53 with Examples](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/dns-port)

> **What is DNS port?**
>
> DNS port is the port assigned to the domain name system. The most frequently used DNS Port is UDP 53. It is the default port for almost all DNS queries. UDP is lightweight and faster than TCP. This can reduce performance overhead on DNS servers.

And don't give admin accounts top other users on your **ubuntu**

Comment: Agrees - although it should be pissible to do the same things on the Ubuntu box using iptables. (Ive not posted it as an answer as its not quite what the OP asked. It may be a bit of an XY problem though.